# Python Tkinter return menu label as string

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, label, return-value

I am trying to somehow return the value of the current menu label using tkinter and python code.

I want to dynamically update `editmenu` depending on the number of serial ports being used, but I am not sure what to do.

I have tried using `list[x].device` already, but when the function is called, it uses a past value of `x` (as expected really, so this doesn't work).

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks!

```
editmenu = Menu(menubar, tearoff=0)
list = serial.tools.list_ports.comports()
for x in range(0, len(list)):
    editmenu.add_command(label=list[x].device, command=lambda:app.setPort())
menubar.add_cascade(label="Port", menu=editmenu)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can pass the port or label via the lambda:

```
editmenu.add_command(label=list[x].device, 
  command=lambda label=list[x].device:app.setPort(label))
```

You then just need to define `setPort` to accept the label as a parameter.